# Typescript Class not visibel inside other class

Tags: javascript, typescript

How do I make one class Server visible inside another class Database in Typescript?
When I try to create an instance of var theServer = new Server(); inside the Database class I get the following error:

```
ReferenceError: Server is not defined
```

Comment: Is the Server class inside a different module? Is that class exported from the module? Is that file referenced in your other class' file?

Comment: It's 2 files: One called Server.ts and the other called Database.ts. With classes called Server and Database.

Comment: Ok, so I assume the classes aren't in modules. Have you tried referencing `Server.ts` in `Database.ts` by putting the line `/// <reference path="Server.ts" />` at the top of `Database.ts`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have script tags in your page for both `Database.js` and `Server.js`.

Comment: This seems like a common correct answer you give. I frequently incorrectly assume the person means it was a compile time error rather than runtime.